# Como fazer o preenchimento de uma lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu preciso realizar o preenchimento de uma lista (sem utilizar pacotes como numpy ou pandas) que possui o um formato parecido com o seguinte:

```
lista1 = [0, 3, 7, 10, 15]
```

Os número são crescentes mas não seguem uma ordem ou padrão. O preenchimento que eu preciso fazer não pode ser com um número, mas sim com algum identificador (uma string genérica como `'falha'` ou `'nan'`, por exemplo). Esse preenchimento precisa ser realizado com base também no tamanho de outra lista com um tamanho `n`. Digamos que o tamanho dessa lista fosse  `i = 20` (ela tem um tamanho crescente com passo de 1):

```
lista2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,..., 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20].
```

A saída do programa seria algo do tipo:

```
0, 0
1, falha
2, falha
3, 3
4, falha
5, falha
6, falha
7, 7
...
15, 15
16, falha
17, falha
18, falha
19, falha
20, falha
```

O preenchimento eu até consegui fazer de certa forma utilizando um `insert`, porém eu obtenho um erro relacionado ao tamanho das listas devido à diferença no final entre as duas.

Segue o que eu consegui:

```
listaf = []
for i in range(len(lista2)):
   if lista2[i] == lista1[i]:
      valorf = lista1[i]
      listaf.append(valorf)
   else:
      valorf = lista1.insert(i, 'falha')
      listaf.append(valorf)
```

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você só quer imprimir o resultado, não precisa guardar em outra lista, nem modificar a `lista1`. Bastaria percorrer as listas e ir imprimindo de acordo com os valores:

```
lista1 = [0, 3, 7, 10, 15]
lista2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

i = j = 0
while i < len(lista1) and j < len(lista2):
    if lista1[i] == lista2[j]: # são iguais, imprime e avança para o próximo
        print(f'{lista1[i]}, {lista2[j]}')
        i += 1
        j += 1
    else: # são diferentes, avança a lista2 até encontrar o elemento igual em lista 1
        while lista2[j] < lista1[i]:
            print(f'{lista2[j]}, falha')
            j += 1

# se ainda faltam elementos de lista2
while j < len(lista2):
    print(f'{lista2[j]}, falha')
    j += 1
```

Ou seja, se forem iguais, eu avanço para o próximo elemento das 2 listas. Se forem diferentes, eu só avanço a `lista2`.

No final, eu vejo se ainda faltou percorrer algum elemento de `lista2` (este algoritmo assume que `lista2` sempre é maior). Também não conferi se os elementos estão em ordem crescente, pois parece que isso já é um pré-requisito do programa.

---

Mas se você quer uma outra lista contendo os elementos de `lista1` e a string "falha" onde faltam os elementos de `lista2`, bastaria trocar para:

```
lista1 = [0, 3, 7, 10, 15]
lista2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

i = j = 0
listaf = []
while i < len(lista1) and j < len(lista2):
    if lista1[i] == lista2[j]: # são iguais, adiciona o valor e avança para o próximo
        listaf.append(lista1[i])
        i += 1
        j += 1
    else: # são diferentes, avança a lista2 até encontrar o elemento igual em lista 1
        while lista2[j] < lista1[i]:
            listaf.append('falha') # adiciona "falha"
            j += 1

# se ainda faltam elementos de lista2, insere várias vezes "falha"
listaf.extend(['falha'] * (len(lista2) - j))
```

Answer (score 1):

Se os valores da segunda lista sempre forem uma [progressão aritmética](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica), você não precisa criá-la em memória, basta usar um [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) para iterar pelos valores e printar apenas os valores que esteja contidos na sua primeira lista.

Para testar o valor está contido com eficiência podemos converter sua `lista1` para um conjunto utilizando [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Dessa maneira o código ficaria mais simples de entender. Veja:

```py
def print_sparse_list(num_list, result_length, default_value="falha"):
    # converte a lista para conjunto
    nums = set(num_list)

    for i in range(result_length):
        # value é i se estiver em `nums`, senão é "falha"
        value = i if i in nums else default_value 
        print(f"{i}, {value}")

# Cria uma lista para exemplificar
lista = [0, 3, 7]

print_sparse_list(lista, 10)
# Saída:
# 0, 0
# 1, falha
# 2, falha
# 3, 3
# 4, falha
# 5, falha
# 6, falha
# 7, 7
# 8, falha
# 9, falha

print_sparse_list(lista, 8, "None")
# 0, 0
# 1, None
# 2, None
# 3, 3
# 4, None
# 5, None
# 6, None
# 7, 7

print_sparse_list(lista, 5, "NaN")
# 0, 0
# 1, NaN
# 2, NaN
# 3, 3
# 4, NaN
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-472671-6333)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar list comprehension:

```py
lista1 = [0, 3, 7, 10, 15]
lista2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8 ,9 ,10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

lista3 = [item if item in lista1 not in lista2 else 'falha' for item in lista2]
```

Sua saída:

```py
print(lista3)

[0, 'falha', 'falha', 3, 'falha', 'falha', 'falha', 7, 'falha', 'falha', 10, 'falha', 'falha', 'falha', 'falha', 15, 'falha', 'falha', 'falha', 'falha', 'falha']
```